# Updating many mongoDB records of a field based on a condition

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, nosql

I have few records in my Mongo DB. The currentStatus field has either of three statuses ("IDLE", "ACTIVE", "SHUTDOWN"). I want to update all records in the currentStatus field from "IDLE" or "ACTIVE" to "SHUTDOWN". I need to make sure they are not in the "SHUTDOWN" state before updating.

The field looks like this:

[image]

Tried this but didn't work.

```
var currentStatusActive = this.collection.find({currentStatus: "ACTIVE"});
var currentStatusIdle = this.collection.find({currentStatus : "IDLE"});

if(currentStatusActive.currentStatus == "ACTIVE" || currentStatusIdle.currentStatus == "IDLE"){
var newStatus = {$set: {currentStatus: "SHUTDOWN"} };
this.collection.updateMany(newStatus, function(err,res){
if (err) throw err;
})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap the filter conditions and the set target inside the mongodb updateMany function.

```
try {
   db.collection.updateMany(
      {"currentStatus": {$in:["ACTIVE","IDLE"]} },
      { $set: { "currentStatus" : "SHUTDOWN" } }
   );
} catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
```

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/ for more explanation.